# How to differentiate between function types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to create type guards that are nested, and as such, they require either a function that returns the result of type checking `isOk(data) => boolean`, or a function that returns a function that returns the result of type checking `isOk()(data) => boolean`. This has to be done to allow the type checking to be nested and reference to either itself it two objects to each other.

This has been implemented all well and good, but no matter what I try I can't seem to find out how to differentiate between those two function types if it is given as an argument.

For example, exporting this is not possible as typescript prevents exporting values with the same name.

[**Minimum reproducible 1**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQBKwMUOwAbsFHALxwAUAlAwHzrb6HQBiAVwB2AYxg4IQgNwBYAFChIsBMlSZcBIlEGjxkhsxAAuOMIDWQiAHchbepwBGECFmAZp8+YujwAZsLEJITgcAGcAFVUmKm5NaBN1Hi1SckoaKAAaOE0ME3NLGxYTJxc3YIBveThquCgyAShgmI1eKFYmHJZZOQBfTwVwHzh-XSCQiKjmpPiuFq0dQMksnLyhC2tbYudXdzhKuRra+sa4Kbi2zu6eoA)

```js
export type ValidatorFunction = (data: unknown) => boolean;
export type ValidatorRetriever = () => ValidatorFunction;

export function isType(validator: ValidatorRetriever, data: unknown): boolean {
    return validator()(data);
}

export function isType(validator: ValidatorFunction, data: unknown): boolean {
    return validator(data);
}
```

similarly using `instanceof` is not possible, as it is used only for classes and not types, as types are discarded during transpile.

[**Minimum reproducible 2**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQBKwMUOwAbsFHALxwAUAlAwHzrb6HQBiAVwB2AYxg4IQgNwBYAFChIsBMlSZcBIlEGjxkhsxAAuOMIDWQiAHchbepwBGECFmAZp8+YujwAZsLEJITgcAGcAFVUmKm5NaBN1Hi1SckoaOgAfLg1ebQC9IQAaOE0ME3NLGxYTJxc3YIBveTgWkN9o2NyQoVCYdxFgCF9spJIyCmpaNia5Vrm4KDIBKGCYnK1WJlKWWVnWgF84YCxQ1Bx2tdG6HB6+0UHhxLi83SDp5vmWxZhl1c6N7a7Ob7D5fJYrOC+bCnXb7IA)

```js
export type ValidatorFunction = (data: unknown) => boolean;
export type ValidatorRetriever = () => ValidatorFunction;

export function isType(validator: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction, data: unknown): boolean {
    if(validator instanceof ValidatorRetriever) {
        return validator()(data);
    } else if(validator instanceof ValidatorFunction) {
        return validator(data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Either the same function name or type detection must exist, as some objects may require either one or both of different validation functions, such as

```js
let object2Validator = undefined;

const object1Validator = object1({
  key: isString, // which would be ValidatorFunction
  children: isArray(() => object2Validator) // which would be ValidatorRetriever
});
object2Validator = object2({
  path: isString,
  children: isArray(object1Validator)
});

if(object2Validator({...})) {
  console.log("Is object 2");
} else {
  console.log("Is not object 2");
}
```

The code examples are very barebones, but the main problem is the following: how to make either one of the previous two minimum reproducibles work?

A. export functions with the same name but different parameters (like `isArray` in the example)

[Minimum reproducible 1 from above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQBKwMUOwAbsFHALxwAUAlAwHzrb6HQBiAVwB2AYxg4IQgNwBYAFChIsBMlSZcBIlEGjxkhsxAAuOMIDWQiAHchbepwBGECFmAZp8+YujwAZsLEJITgcAGcAFVUmKm5NaBN1Hi1SckoaKAAaOE0ME3NLGxYTJxc3YIBveThquCgyAShgmI1eKFYmHJZZOQBfTwVwHzh-XSCQiKjmpPiuFq0dQMksnLyhC2tbYudXdzhKuRra+sa4Kbi2zu6eoA)

or

B. differentiate between two different function types `ValidatorFunction` and `ValidatorRetriever` (alternative to different function implementations)

[Minimum reproducible 2 from above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQBKwMUOwAbsFHALxwAUAlAwHzrb6HQBiAVwB2AYxg4IQgNwBYAFChIsBMlSZcBIlEGjxkhsxAAuOMIDWQiAHchbepwBGECFmAZp8+YujwAZsLEJITgcAGcAFVUmKm5NaBN1Hi1SckoaOgAfLg1ebQC9IQAaOE0ME3NLGxYTJxc3YIBveTgWkN9o2NyQoVCYdxFgCF9spJIyCmpaNia5Vrm4KDIBKGCYnK1WJlKWWVnWgF84YCxQ1Bx2tdG6HB6+0UHhxLi83SDp5vmWxZhl1c6N7a7Ob7D5fJYrOC+bCnXb7IA)

Comment: What is `(...) => boolean`? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.

Comment: I'm not seeing why you're using generic `T` here; can't you just remove it and ask the same question like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleyXm)?  The generics only seem to make the question more complicated without actually having much to do with the underlying issue: telling apart function types at runtime

Comment: @jcalz i'm trying to modify an existing NPM package "type-guard-validator" with stricter definitions in order for it to allow validator retrieval later on instead of just directly assigning it some validators, as the original method doesn't allow for nested types. As there will be multiple different types of interfaces in the application, it would be a waste to implement individual validator functions for each of them when a simple object listing the keys and possible values could do the job. This may take a while as I'm trying to build a somewhat sensible representation of the problem

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what is "this" in "this may take a while"?  Are you planning to provide a [mre] or are you referring to something else?  Using my version of your code one could try inspecting the `length` property of the function like [this](//tsplay.dev/wRlA1m), but it's *fragile*; there is no guarantee that a function of "zero" length acts the way you want.  Does that address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I checked your fragile example and it seems to work perfectly! Although your example is fragile, I'd guess that could be circumvented by examining the return type of the function or something similar (out of scope for this question). In that case it'd be fine if it would throw an error (and preferable to do so). I've added some minimal reproducibles if someone stumbles upon this later on. You can post your third message example link as an answer and I'll accept it for you. (it can differentiate between the two function types which was the goal B of this question)

Comment: I'm writing up an answer now.  Please put the [mre] as plain text in the question itself; a playground link is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice by itself, and the code in the question is still invalid TS with `(...)=>boolean` and unmotivated generics.

Comment: Done, I've made the code pieces so that they can be copy pasted without the need for generics and the (...)=>boolean has been clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither JavaScript nor TypeScript have "true" function overloads in the sense that you can have two *different* functions with the same name that differ by number/types of argument.  TypeScript's [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) allow you to have multiple call signatures, but there's still just one function implementation, and that implementation needs to be written in such a way that it can handle all of the possible call signatures.   it is not possible to "export functions with the same name but different parameters".

---

That means we need to try to write a single `isType()` function that can somehow differentiate between a `ValidatorRetriever` input and a `ValidatorFunction` input at runtime.   If you can figure out a way to do this, then you can write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to let the TypeScript compiler know that's what you're doing.  So it would look like this:

```
function isRetriever(v: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction): v is ValidatorRetriever {
    /* implement this somehow */
}
```

The `isRetriever()` function takes an input that is either a `ValidatorRetriever` or a `ValidatorFunction` and returns a `boolean` value.  If it returns `true` then the compiler knows that the input is actually a `ValidatorRetriever`; otherwise if it returns `false` then the compiler knows that the input is actually a `ValidatorFunction`.  This lets you write `isType()` as follows:

```
function isType(validator: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction, data: unknown): boolean {
    return isRetriever(validator) ? validator()(data) : validator(data)
}
```

So the question now is... how do we implement `isRetriever()`?

---

Unfortunately there's really no *proper* way to do this. JavaScript has a weak type system. You can't ask JavaScript about the parameter or return types of a function without calling it.  There *is* a [`Function.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) which tells you the *number* of arguments that a function expects.  So potentially you could just check whether `v.length` is `0` (for a `ValidatorRetriever`) or `1` (for a `ValidatorFunction`).  And indeed this will work for simple cases:

```
function isRetriever(v: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction): v is ValidatorRetriever {
    return v.length === 0; 
}

function str() {
    return (x: unknown) => typeof x === "string"
}
console.log(isType(str, "abc")) // okay, true

function num(x: unknown) {
    return typeof x === "number"
}
console.log(isType(num, "abc")) // okay, false
```

But you can't rely on the `length` property this way.  Functions in JavaScript can have [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and accept any number of arguments, but this does not contribute to `length`:

```
function oopsieDoodle(...args: any[]) {
    return args.length === 0
}

console.log(isType(oopsieDoodle, "abc")) //  RUNTIME ERROR! validator() is not a function
```

The `oopsieDoodle()` function is a valid `ValidatorFunction`, since it does accept a single `unknown` argument (you can call `oopsieDoodle(x)` where `x` is of type `unknown`.  [Function type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) can sometimes be surprising) and returns a `boolean`.  But our `isRetriever()` implementation erroneously decides that it's a `ValidatorRetriever` because the `length` property is `0`.  And we get a runtime error.

Maybe this isn't a big deal to you, and you'll accept that some inputs to `isType()` will cause runtime errors.  If it *is* a big deal then you quickly run into unpleasant ways of trying to deal with it.  Like, maybe you can test it by calling it and then seeing if the return type is a `boolean` or a function?

```
function isRetriever(v: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction): v is ValidatorRetriever {
    return typeof v("TESTING") === "function"; 
}
```

This should work as long as `v` doesn't actually explode if you pass it an argument when it's not expecting one.  And as long as calling it doesn't have unintended consequences (e.g., if it's stateful or slow).  But passing dummy arguments to a function for the sole purpose of seeing what it does is a strange practice.

---

Maybe either of the above is acceptable to you for your particular use cases.  In general, for future readers, it is not a great idea to try to probe functions at runtime for their types.

A better general solution is to refactor so that you are comparing things which have been explicitly marked with distinguishable properties, like a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type ValidatorRetriever = { (): (x: unknown) => boolean; type: "ret" }
type ValidatorFunction = { (x: unknown): boolean; type: "fun" }

function isType(validator: ValidatorRetriever | ValidatorFunction, data: unknown): boolean {
    return validator.type === "ret" ? validator()(data) : validator(data)
}

function str() {
    return (x: unknown) => typeof x === "string"
}
str.type = "ret" as const;
console.log(isType(str, "abc")) // okay, true

function num(x: unknown) {
    return typeof x === "number"
}
num.type = "fun" as const;
console.log(isType(num, "abc")) // okay, false

function oopsieDoodle(...args: any[]) {
    return args.length === 0
}
oopsieDoodle.type = "fun" as const; // <-- if you make this "ret" you'll see errors
console.log(isType(oopsieDoodle, "abc")) // okay, false
```

Instead of relying on built-in function behavior, you're adding a `type` property to the functions in question and looking at that to discriminate between a `ValidatorRetriever` and a `ValidatorFunction`.

Again, this might be unnecessary for your particular use cases, and if `length` or test calling the function is acceptable then you can do that.  But discriminated unions are well-supported in TypeScript in a way that runtime function inspection is not.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7APYCcBKFhZIQBuEWUAvFABQCUlAfLIqutgGICuAdgMbBIM3ANwBYAFChIzZGkxYufAUMo0AHgC4oPANbcMAd270KTAEYYMCCHBESJ3OAFsIAZzBxe0ADIRuAc2AACygAb3txKCioADMefkFuKCRXPAIiUixqYi14WTZcfEISMigAHxlWeUUEoVotYmTXSrlsNOLMsIlonqgsfE4sJOIAOmsA4MoKKgAGYSgAegWoYJSm2Kw4fyRrbuiAXwieuKVEpoAVcAhsllasXNuC9ozSiryqjnjlbgAaKDk4FpdPojPUoBYrDYkuFIr0ov1gIMkilniUssRHvJ6AB+KAY-LyOjUAH0BqY7DE9BwWh7KKHcS02JfM6uAh0LqwuEIpHqIHcPSGYyMFZXDAxKBqKZUABErMIAWljPpPV4QlckLGGH81BSl0g1Dlf2lcDMvGltHoSygGB0cBAfwInAgR2iJ1qSW4nCc1E02n5IKFMLh8IGQxFkDFEqlUGlnqcZjIis5UGV0VV3HV1k12t1V2ocaNJrNFsWyxtdr+MUQrmdDOTbu+1owYFcRAAIpYUNZqCNe3AsP5XFpbCAANoAXXoQeD3LD-cHYz8gRC01mSsZBBAHODUHTmYg2Z1rj110sLfbneshdN5sty0AvBuAUp2oDgAKoAOXOAEkALIAUSgP8cBwAB5HAAEI8XJLJ6DWfRgCgOAmVOIQlV3dBeBCagICnRkVTVDUEC1bCaWTekJHI8RHBcdxPGgNIkRPDkXSiBszhRIoXnRB4CTaTi0XKFoChqb4wUaNZ3juVFOmnLlQySKQIEjYhqGlc4-wAZW-d8AHFzWjaU2KEaV5itVZmicJB-CCBCE1iJBuGgMxOAQkAME4AByfp0IQZAAhWIJoCM7h1zrY5mRUXN9XxD57iE+RpNeeLPhQ35-ipPkBVBLQIWsWxtxneSmkS9FoJxKDeJgylgGpKAyUq6rqVCxlgqgOV2Vk3pZySH1MoDEwmEUyNJVXGM5Qc-wkx6VMoj3QjiKi65DRjItb1La1bXtFYsCdFjkPdKA416v0ssDPDom68MlPFEbphjOMEywKaDkZOasyInNjzzAsVpvEsrXLLaqwQGs9tas9WwgDsMC7a5exGech0Q7gx0nAq5MROcB1cRcJhXO6ZlC-CM3mz6T2oCGLxhq9fuLO8NorWJq1rCJKOotwPC8KA2xSXhCCcV9mOTRTksKdIBKoUIaDBY7gUFAbwUsPKRCurRpQRaUUw3K5RZEs5Jd5E7+pypWoXmRS1ZOTXKPC1KLjzGK7h42KSsEyThIitKAT6+WTchfLOp6S7HYKEYRdG9X8E13EQ8JWhGtJCrYoT5r609tq2Vw5Mg6K2X-Xl4UhpugzxoVInojlMOdZlDXEOaPdgDEZM3oPD6j3J5bjT++nAYdHaWbTu2jt9OXQXRrqiqLqMI4exNy6iOMq+kGUrbr3c1Ub16CPehavv1H6u7p9be6ZkGB9tg7Kahy84b7bHhxRics53S7Edx5do0JsjGSv6HYaX6AK8eCazgPXDeTdib7kPItCmzZIZ-xpofNaANNqVmZqzCIQA)